# Deserialize List in List Json C#

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialization

I have list of questions in JSON. Each of them contains list of answers. When I'm deserializing it, list of answers doesn't deserialize. I'm just getting questions with empty lists of answers. How can i fix this?
**My deserializing**

```
List<QuestionTxt> myDeserializedObjList = (List<QuestionTxt>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"d:\test.txt"), typeof(List<QuestionTxt>));
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "1",
                "text": "First"
            },
            {
                "answer": "Second",
                "text": "2"
            }
        ],
        "cost": 1.0,
        "count": 2,
        "image": false,
        "imagePath": null,
        "name": "Numbers",
        "about": "Numbers",
        "solve": false,
        "type": "Сonformity",
        "Id": "cnf0"
    },
    {
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "+",
                "text": "One"
            },
            {
                "answer": "-",
                "text": "Two"
            }
        ],
        "cost": 1.0,
        "count": 2,
        "image": false,
        "imagePath": null,
        "name": "Numbers 2",
        "about": "Numbers 2",
        "solve": false,
        "type": "One",
        "Id": "rdb0"
    }
]
```

**QuestionTxt**

[image: Answer class]

**Answer**

```
class Answer
{
    private string text_;
    private string answer_;

    public Answer(string text, string answer)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public string answer { get => answer_; set => answer_ = value; }
    public string text { get => text_; set => text_ = value; }
}
```

Comment: Show `QuestionTxt` class

Comment: @Fabio added QuestionTxt

Comment: We also need to see the answer object. Please paste the code into your question, do not link images.

Comment: @DougEFresh Stack saying that it to much code in my questions, so i can't add text. https://pastebin.com/HzkawT7M

Comment: Remove the `Answer` constructor with parameters or add another constructor with no parameters (i.e. how do you think it will be able to construct one with no parameters?)

Comment: `answers` property should be changed to `public` or add an `JsonPropertyAttribute` to it.

Comment: And I think you should start using auto-properties `public string Answer { get; set; }`

Comment: @Fabio changed Answer to public, added constructor with no parameters, problem is still the same

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property `QuestionTxt.answers` should be `public` (you have `internal`)

```
public class QuestionTxt
{
    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }  // notice public!
    public string name { get; set; }

    public QuestionTxt()
    {
        answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to keep it `internal` - use `JsonPropertyAttribute`

```
public class QuestionTxt
{
    [JsonProperty()]
    internal List<Answer> answers { get; set; }  // notice internal!
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}
```

And of course all classes you want deserialize should have parameterless constructor.

As a notice with `JsonPropertyAttribute` you will get a freedom to follow .Net conventions with property names, without violating json conventions

```
public class QuestionTxt
{
    [JsonProperty("answers")]
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}

public class Answer
{
    [JsonProperty("answer")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "Property QuestionTxt.answers should be public (you have internal)"

This solved my problem, thank you. And thanks to everyone who helped me here, i think that comments about constructor helped me too.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer class needs to have an overload that takes no parameters like this. When Newtonsoft tries to instantiate the object it doesn't know what to hand to the parameters of the constructor.

```
public class Answer
{
     public Answer()
     {
     }
     public Answer(string text, string answer)
     {
         this.text = text;
         this.answer = answer;
     }

     public string AnswerName { get;set; }
     public string Text { get;set; }
}
```

Your QuestionTxt class has this:
`private List<Answer> answers_ = new List<Answer)();`
try making that line `private List<Answer> answers_;` because this is not in a constructor. Your then have an internal property with the same name as pointed out in the other answer. 
I would copy it and fix it but it is an image and I'm not going to type out the whole thing.

EDIT: Added info about the QuestionTxt class. Fabio in the comments was right, to improve on your code the properties can have auto accessors. Also changing the answer property to `AnswerName` to separate it from the class name for clarity.

Comment: changed Answer to public, added constructor with no parameters, problem is still the same

Comment: change your json file to capitalize the Answer and Text properties if you changed it in the object.

Comment: Actually probably not good to have a property name the same as the object. Let's change it to AnswerName